# How to properly use http.ReadResponse in Go?

Tags: http, go

I am trying to send a request to a server and receive a response using `http.ReadResponse` function but the problem is that it is blocked and nothing is received.

First I thought that I use incorrect-made request so now I am using `nil` as the second arguement to send default GET request (as it is described in a documentation) but nothing has been changed.

Maybe I use `bufio.Reader` incorrectly but I really do not think so because `http.ReadRequest` works fine.

```golang
func main() {
    var conn, _ = net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:80")
    defer conn.Close()

    var (
        reader        = bufio.NewReader(conn)
        response, err = http.ReadResponse(reader, nil)
    )
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(*response)
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn’t really make sense. Can you explain what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: @JimB As I have just said this code: 1. connects to the server; 2. sends the request to it and receives the ```response``` (in one operation of ```http.ReadResponse```); 3. outputs a ```response``` structure in a console.

Comment: This code does not make any request. Have you looked at any of the documentation for making an [http request](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#pkg-overview)?

Comment: @JimB https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse says: "The req parameter optionally specifies the Request that corresponds to this Response. If nil, a GET request is assumed." Whatever let's say we construct the request obviously and pass it to the function: ```var request = http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil); response = http.ReadResponse(reader, nil)```. The effect is the same.

Comment: But you haven't actually sent any request, so there's nothing to read in either case. `ReadResponse` doesn't send a request, it. just parses a response. You probably won't ever need `ReadResponse`.

Comment: @ghostinecatnewyear: *"...the problem is that it is blocked and nothing is received..."* -  to make it more explicit what JimB said: since you don't send a request the server will not send a response - which means that your attempt to read the response will just block while waiting for a response which never got send.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad: I interpreted a [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse)'s function description incorrectly. I thought that the `http.ReadResponse` function sends the request passed to it before receiving the response ("Otherwise why is the request parameter needed?" - I thought). But as I can see now this parameter is needed for other purposes and perhaps I guess for what but this is beyond the scope of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Your request will not work. By creating a socket, you are sending a layer 4 request when you should be sending a layer 7 request (http is part of the Application layer). Fortunately, the `http` library in go already has implementations for `Get`. So, to accomplish what you want, just do the following:

```
resp, _ http.Get("localhost:80")
body, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

And then you could throw the body into say Go's JSON Handler or turn it into a string.